# JavaScript timer not working on multiple instance

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Below is a result of a loop and I want to run timer to count up to the set time for each of the loop result.

```
<span id="time" data-time="{{ $user->created_at->addHours(config('app.timer')) }}" data-url="{{ url('/TimePay/'.$user->id)}}"></span>

<span id="time" data-time="{{ $user->created_at->addHours(config('app.timer')) }}" data-url="{{ url('/TimePay/'.$user->id)}}"></span>

<span id="time" data-time="{{ $user->created_at->addHours(config('app.timer')) }}" data-url="{{ url('/TimePay/'.$user->id)}}"></span>
```

The timer script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('[data-time]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this))
    var $this = $(this),
      finalTime = $(this).data('time'),
      url       = $(this).data('url')

    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date(finalTime).getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Display the result in an element with id="demo"
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

      // If the count down is finished, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);
  })
})
```

So am using Laravel and jQuery to run the timer.

I want assistance with the code because it is not working.

Comment: 1- An `id` must be unique... Can't use the same multiple times. 2- The `x` variable you use to store the interval is overwritten on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to "save" you intervals in an array.
If you do not do it, it gets overwritten on each loop iteration.

Then, to refer to the right `span` element, you have to get the iteration `index` for later use in an `.eq()` method.
You **can't** use an `id` in a loop, since it has to be unique.

Have a look at comments within the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // an arrary to store the intervals created.
  var timerArray = [];

  $('[data-time]').each(function(index) {
    console.log($(this).data("time"));

    var finalTime = $(this).data('time');

    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date(finalTime).getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // this Index will be used to refer to the right span.
      var thisIndex = index;
      console.log("interval "+thisIndex);

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now an the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Leading zeros...
      if(hours<10){hours="0"+hours}
      if(minutes<10){minutes="0"+minutes}
      if(seconds<10){seconds="0"+seconds}

      // Display the result in an element with id="demo"
      $('[data-time]').eq(thisIndex).html( days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s " );

      // If the count down is finished, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(timerArray[thisIndex]);
        $('[data-time]').eq(thisIndex).html("EXPIRED");
      }
    }, 1000);

    // Place this timer in an array... So it won't be overwritten.
    timerArray.push(x);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span data-time="07/08/2017 12:30:00"></span><br>
<br>
<span data-time="07/10/2017 19:50:30"></span><br>
<br>
<span data-time="07/12/2017 5:24:24"></span><br>
<br>
```

Run the snippet in "full page" or look at this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/awRBaY?editors=1011).

Comment: Thank you very much you save me from a lot of stress i want to reward you.